# Aplicar borde solo a un td

Tags: html, html5, css

Tengo las dos siguientes simples tablas, lo que quiero hacer es aplicarle el `border` solo un par de elementos `td` pero que queden con el mismo estilo como cuando se aplica a toda la tabla como tal, esto es lo que llevo y no logro recrear el estilo, ¿qué puedo corregir para lograr lo que espero?

```css
*{
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

td{
  width: 50px;
}

.border{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td >bar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="border">foo</td>
      <td class="border">bar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no se si te entendi del todo pero revisa mi respuesta

Comment: ¿Para que quieres ponerle el mismo estilo a una tabla con dos clases si lo que quieres es que tenga el mismo estilo que `border="1"`? ¿Por qué no utilizas directamente `border="1"` también en la segunda tabla?

Comment: El estilo del borde con el atributo `border` es relativo, se ve de forma diferente en distinto navegadores. Los atributos `border`, `align`, `cellspacing` y `cellspadding` que estás usando están desaconsejados y actualmente se usan propiedades CSS para eso. Si lo haces con CSS tendrás más consistencia, se verá igual en todos los navegadores.

Comment: @Error404 el atributo `border` no funciona en los `td`, de todas formas como digo en el otro comentario hace años que se desaconseja usar atributos HTML para dar formato.

Comment: @blonfu Me refiero, si le quiere poner un borde a toda la tabla igual que en la primera tabla, mi pregunta es porque no pone `border="1"` directamente también en la segunda tabla, no en el td. Y sí, yo también estoy a favor de que se eliminen los atributos para las tablas.

Comment: @Error404 es cierto, dices en la tabla, me equivoqué. De todas formas el OP parece que quiere el mismo estilo que tiene en la tabla de arriba pero en unas celdas concretas, o eso he entendido yo

Comment: @blonfu Ah, igual se refiere a tener el mismo padding en las celdas esas. La verdad que no lo sé. Esperaremos a que el OP edite la pregunta con algo más de información.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

td{
  width: 50px;
}

#uno,#dos{
border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td >bar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr class="">
      <td class="border">foo</td>
      <td class="border">bar</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="uno">foo</td>
      <td id="dos">bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```